# Netduino powerd by USB wall charger

Tags: power, usb, netduino

I have a IPhone wall charger. Can I plug my netduino into it to power it via USB?

Comment: I'm jealous that you even have a netduino.  I'm still waiting for one to be in stock!

Comment: Amazon's got them. http://www.amazon.com/Secret-Labs-Netduino/dp/B003XT25TY/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1292996297&sr=8-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. I'm guessing you have [this little gizmo](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPod_2ndGen_USB_Power_Adapter-EN.pdf) and a random USB extension cable. Looking at the [Netduino schematics](http://netduino.com/netduino/schematic.pdf) you can clearly see that the USB input is fused, kinda buffered (can see current limiting op amp and RC PDN arrangement, if I'm reading it correctly), and regulated. The Apple product is supposed to output 5V; I didn't check to see which LDO the Netduino is using, but it'll likely have a drop ~0.3V, however there's a pass transistor as well which may bring that up a bit (maybe ~0.1V drop) -- looks like it may be on the fence between linear and saturation, though, so don't count on it. Surely the Netduino will be fine with a bit less than 5V.

Comment: the Netduino advertises "input: 7.5 - 12.0 VDC or USB powered" They are being smart on making sure that the regulator power doesn't fight with the USB power.

Comment: @Kellenjb, I think I could learn something by studying their supply setup a bit more. It does look pretty smart.

Comment: Agreed, me too. I am not positive as to what exactly they are doing, but I trust that it works as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

The Netduino requires power of 7.5-12v on its power connector. However, the Netduino can also pull it's power from the 5v USB connector. So yes, your IPhone wall charger should work just fine for you.